# How do I submit code that will be beneficial to others?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, asking-questions, scope

Hey everyone,

I've been working on a problem - which I successfuly solved on my own - and I would like to submit it to Stack Overflow.  However, Stack Overflow is for asking questions and getting answers.

And it seems redundant to 'ask a question when I already know the answer'.

Is there anyway I can publish on here solutions to problems that I think others might have?  For instance, I've just pieced together bits and pieces of code from five different websites and was able to get the "joyGetPosExA" API to work within VB2008.

Basically, how to use gamepads within VB2008 using standard Windows API and NOT using DirectX.

Every other sample I found searching for this solution on the Internet involved using DirectX, Managed DirectX, DirectInput, XInput, XNA, C#, etc.  Considering the amount of posts I waded through of people asking the same question as I had on the Interwebs - and none of it working for them - I figured I should contribute to the community by posting my code, which does indeed work.

How/where should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fact is that you had a question in the first place. This means someone is likely to have the same problem at some point in time.

I don't think community wiki is relevant for this, so ask the question, wait on your answer and then two days later add it. This will give other people a chance to show their own solutions to your problem and you may even learn something new in the process.

Obviously you can still accept your own answer, but give others a chance to solve the problem as well.

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning in the question that you have a solution though so people don't spend too much time on it?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did for [my first question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787802/how-do-i-update-a-linked-server-table-where-alias-is-required-in-sql-server-20), which I solved just as I had formatted the question. I even gave the answer to someone else.

Comment: +1. I just hope that by saying you already have an answer you don't get complaints from some people (though I am not betting on it).