# Answering your own question... Is it bad form?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Should I not answer my own questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions)
>   [How do I submit code that will be beneficial to others?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55152/how-do-i-submit-code-that-will-be-beneficial-to-others)

I had a problem today that I ended up not posting on Stack Overflow.  The solution was non-trivial and I feel like I got lucky in a Google search.

Is it bad form for me to post the question on SO and then answer it?  I'd only want to do that so that anyone else can benefit from the knowledge.

Comment: Indeed, but that seems to be more of - "I posted the question and later I found the answer"... but point taken.

Comment: Posible duplicate of "How do I submit code that will be beneficial to others?" then! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55152/how-do-i-submit-code-that-will-be-beneficial-to-others

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not bad form. It's expressly welcomed.

Comment: first I read that as "no, it's not expressly welcomed" and I was like wha?